# Using R shiny for automation

Tags: r, shiny

I want to automate the process of refreshing a dashboard from the data prepared in my shiny application. The idea to start the refresh is when user clicks on a particular button in the app. For this I need a way to start running a batch file when that button is clicked. Any idea how to incorporate this batch file execution in the R shiny app?

Comment: You can use the `system()` function in R to run system commands